# hive failed execution error return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mapredtask

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have one query. It is executing fine on Hive CLI and returning the result. But when I am executing it with the help of Hive JDBC, I am getting an error below:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:192)
```

What is the problem? Also I am starting the Hive Thrift Server through Shell Script. (I have written a shell script which has command to start Hive Thrift Server) Later I decided to start Hive thrift Server manually by typing command as:

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~/hive-0.7.1$ bin/hive --service hiveserver
Starting Hive Thrift Server
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10000.
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:99)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:80)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer.main(HiveServer.java:384)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:186)

hadoop@ubuntu:~/hive-0.7.1$
```

Please help me out from this.
Thanks

Comment: Hey, I'm getting this exact same error. Can you post your solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this error :
`java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuer`

Go to this link :

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_Hive.html

and add

```
**hadoop-0.20-core.jar
hive/lib/hive-exec-0.7.1.jar
hive/lib/hive-jdbc-0.7.1.jar
hive/lib/hive-metastore-0.7.1.jar
hive/lib/hive-service-0.7.1.jar
hive/lib/libfb303.jar
lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar    
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar**
```

to the class path of your project , add this jars from the lib of hadoop and hive, and try the code. and also add the path of hadoop, hive, and hbase(if your are using) lib folder path to the project class path, like you have added the jars.

and for the second error you got

type

```
**netstat -nl | grep 10000**
```

if it shows something means hive server is already running. the second error comes only when the port you are specifying is already acquired by some other process, by default server port is 10000 so very with the above netstat command which i said.

Note : suppose you have connected using code exit from ... bin/hive of if you are connected through bin/hive > then code will not connect because i think (not sure) only one client can connect to the hive server.

do above steps hopefully will solve your problem.

NOTE : exit from cli when you are going to execute the code, and dont start cli while code is being executing.

Answer (score 1):

Might be some issue with permission, just try some query like "SELECT * FROM " which won't start MR jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to paste these property before the codes.

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
set hive.auto.convert.join = false;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=100000;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=10000;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).